# How can I start a career in developing software for High end DSLRs?

Tags: dslr, careers

I've been interested in this for quite a long time now, but just recently it occurred to me that i want to do this as a career, but i Haven't got a clue as to how or where to start from, I'm about to graduate with an IT degree this year, majoring in Artificial intelligence and I'd wanna work on programing cameras and developing software to be used on the hardware it self. Any pointers as to how can i start with that would be great.

I've looked at sites such as nikon and canon for the SDK but it's only via requests to registered companies.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about careers and programming

Answer (score 4):

1. Learn (if you don't know already) C/C++ - it is THE language for embedded systems (no, I don't like it, but this is the way it is)
2. Learn how a (dSLR) camera works as a machine. Of course, you need to buy one - highly recommended a Canon (recommended 5D Mk2 or, better, 5D Mk3) because of the latest point in my list.
3. Learn to be a photographer - learn his/her needs. (read a lot from the experience of the elders, shot a lot of things in your spare time etc.)
4. Learn assembly / how the internal parts of a computer works (especially the [CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIGIC) - mainly ARM architecture - because of my latest point of my list)
5. Learn the basics of a real-time Operating System ([VxWorks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VxWorks) or, if you find info, [DryOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRYOS) which is [Canon's proprietary embedded OS](http://web.archive.org/web/20080116050120/http://www.canon.com/technology/canon_tech/explanation/dryos.html))
6. Go at [Magic Lantern](http://www.magiclantern.fm/) site read, ask & download everything. Of course, you must install it on your camera. "If it breaks you can keep both pieces!" (TM) :-)

Note: Magic Lantern is a really great piece of software. It will boost a lot the capabilities of your camera. I have it on my dSLR.

Comment: +1 That last point is priceless. Getting into some relevant code will be immeasurably helpful.

Comment: @Kobunite: Yes - is the gist of the answer. And, in fact, all the other points are written to sustain the last one. To really understand what and why it is there.

Comment: I know about all the things in the list, except for operating Systems, Magic lantern was developed using reverse engineering and it wasn't using the official SDK, its a great way indeed to get an idea about how things work under the hood but is it enough ? , I have 60D and I had 600D before

Answer (score 1):

Take a **Computational Photography** or **"Computer Vision"** course, or read a book, and see in which of its subfields you can contribute to the greater good, earn money and have fun.

There are also cameras forming parts of other systems, e.g. on microscopes, on assembly lines , on satellites; and software for these devices needs to be written, but this is not necessarily image processing software.